# Error saving Docker images to AWS S3 bucket from private Docker Registry

Tags: amazon-s3, docker, amazon-iam, docker-registry

I'm trying to set up a private Docker Registry and save images to AWS S3 instance. The Registry seems to be working fine -- it starts up ok and I can authenticate to it over https. The problem I'm having is that I'm getting an error saving to S3, so I assume there is some permission problem with the S3 IAM policy.

The `docker run` command looks like this:

```
docker run -p 443:5000 \
  --link redis:redis \
  -e REGISTRY_STORAGE=s3 \
  -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET=my-docker-registry \
  -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY=**** \
  -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY=**** \
  -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION=us-east-1 \
  -v `pwd`/auth:/auth \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/my.com_chain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/my.com.key \
  -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_CACHE_BLOBDESCRIPTOR=redis \
  -e REGISTRY_REDIS_ADDR=redis:6379 \
  registry:2.5
```

And the S3 IAM policy looks like this:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-docker-registry"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
              "s3:PutObject",
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:DeleteObject",
              "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
              "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-docker-registry/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

The error log entry is:

```
level=error msg="error resolving upload: s3aws: AccessDenied: Access Denied\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: 2B224..." auth.user.name=my-user go.version=go1.6.3 http.request.host=my.domain.com http.request.id=13b79c07-... http.request.method=PATCH http.request.remoteaddr="xx.xx.xx.xx:41392" http.request.uri="/v2/my-test/blobs/uploads/467d94ea-2a77...?_state=zQd-..." http.request.useragent="docker/1.12.0 go/go1.6.3 git-commit/8eab123 kernel/4.4.15-moby os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.0 \\(darwin\\))" instance.id=8a8db6f1-8fe4 vars.name=my-test vars.uuid=467d94ea-2a77 version=v2.5.0
```

I've used a similar policy for file uploads in other apps, so I'm not sure where the problem is. What do I need to change in the IAM policy to allow the registry to save to the S3 bucket?

Comment: Can you mention which registry you are using? Elastic Container Service?

Comment: I'm using my own registry, Dockerfile is in post.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured it out - not sure if something changed with how Docker saves image files but it seems you now need to add **`s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads`** to the bucket-level permission (middle block below, IAM shown in full for completeness):

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-docker-registry"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
              "s3:PutObject",
              "s3:GetObject",
              "s3:DeleteObject",
              "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
              "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-docker-registry/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Seems to work well now.

Next steps are to create a docker-compose file with the above `docker run` args, add a redis container to that, and it's a full private registry solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the S3 IAM role is assigned to the IAM user whose access key is being used. You can also assign this role to the EC2 instance and avoid using this access key.

Comment: Thanks @shankar-p-s -- it works if I change the IAM Actions to wildcard `*`, which I would rather not do, I just need to figure out which permission I'm missing and where. Not sure I can assign the role to the EC2 instance since I'm running the registry in a container, and also want it to be portable.